# How to create a method similar to ForEach

Tags: c#

This is purely academic, but how would I create a method like the ForEach?

Say if I wanted to do something like the following:

```
 SomeTenumerable.MyOwnFunction(x =>
         {
            x.Id = 0;
            x.Order_Id = 0;
         });
```

Note: I've only just got familiar with `func<T,TResult>`, so I'm not sure if it's the same thing.

Extra points if you can tell me the proper name/label of what I'm trying to achieve, I'm guessing it's some sort of delegate?

Comment: The C# `foreach` statement isn't a function, so what does it mean to create a function that is like it? There is a `ForEach()` method in the `List<T>` type. You can see how that's implemented here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#0e5a9cf0a310b9e5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo here - https://dotnetfiddle.net/v7JKoo

.Each extension I use regularly - taken from http://extensionmethod.net/csharp/ienumerable-t/each-t

```
public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
{
    if (items == null) return;

     foreach (var item in items)
        action(item);
}
```

Example:

```
var items = new List<Item>();
// populate items
items.Each(item => item.DoSomething());
```

Yes you are passing in a delegate (here it is an Action) to perform on each item

PS if you are looking to return items look at linqs .Where or .Select

Comment: How could `items` be `null`? I guess extension methods can be called statically as well?

Comment: @PaulBellora: extension methods are _always_ called statically. They are static methods. And yes, the reference passed as `this` can be `null`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho nice catch! Late night coding fail - putting down the keyboard now

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is create an extension method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx))

ForEach is a method in the List class (you can see the code [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,0e5a9cf0a310b9e5)). Since you cannot add a method to the class, you can create an extension method that lives in your project but can be used as it was part of the original List class.

Let's say your items use this interface

```
public interface IYourInterface
{
    int Id;
    int Order_Id;
}
```

You create a static method in a static class:

```
static class HelperMethods
{
    public static void ResetAll(this List<IYourInterface> collection)
    {
        collection.ForEach(x =>
        {
            x.Id = 0;
            x.Order_Id = 0;
        });
    }
}
```

And then use the method on any instance of List.

```
var collection = new List<IYourInterface>();
collection.ResetAll();

var otherStuff = new List<string>();
// This won't work because because List<string> cannot
// be converted to List<IYourInterface>
// otherStuff.ResetAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Property class

```
Public MyClass
{
  public static int Id {get;set;}
  public static int Order_Id{get;set;} 
}
```

You can set it like this

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myclass = new IEnumerable<MyClass>(
{
    Id = 0;
    Order_Id = 0;
});
```

You can query through, serach throw etc.

See this question, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397887/using-lambda-expressions-trees-with-ienumerable) The question itself not the anwer.